# singleton public static final

Tags: java, singleton

I've been wondering about singletons in Java. By convention, a singleton is set up something like this:

```
private static MyClass instance = null;
public static MyClass getInstance(){
    if (instance == null){
        instance = new MyClass();
    }
    return instance;
}
private MyClass(){}
```

Recently I've switched to using the following:

```
public static final MyClass instance = new MyClass();
private MyClass(){}
```

This is a lot shorter, faster as there's no null-check, and typing `MyClass.instance` feels nicer to me than typing `MyClass.getInstance()`. Is there any reason why the second is not the mainstream way to do this?

Comment: You're conflating singletons and lazy instantiation.

Comment: The first version isn't thread-safe. The second one is (as @biziclop pointed out :P).

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar What isn't thread safe about the second example?

Comment: But what if the asker is just writing apps that are not meant to be multi-threaded? Then I think he does not care about thread safety that much. And thread safety was not even the point of this question. @VinodMadyalkar

Comment: @biziclop - Thanks for reminding me to fill my coffee mug:P

Comment: Thread-safety is indeed a good one, as I am using multiple threads. The second method is indeed not lazy-loaded, but from what I understand that's only an advantage if the class only gets used later on in the program, right? This class gets called pretty much right away.

Comment: Note that there's a third idiom for lazy initialisation of singletons: the [initialisation-on-demand holder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom). This combines the simplicity and JLS-guaranteed thread-safety of your second sample with the lazy initialisation of the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version creates the instance the first time it  is actually needed, while the second (the shorter) runs the constructor as soon as the class [is initialized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4)

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the
>   first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant
>     variable (§4.12.4).
> - T is a top level class (§7.6), and an assert statement (§14.10)
>     lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed. [...]
>
> Invocation of certain reflective methods in class Class and in
>   package java.lang.reflect also causes class or interface initialization.

The initialization upon first usage is a performance improvement that may speed up the startup of the application if the code in the constructor makes expensive operations. On the other hand, the second version is straightforward to read and is automatically thread-safe.

Anyway, the state of the art is not creating singleton in either ways: for a bunch of KB you can get dependency injection libraries that make it working for you, and also handle more complex scenarios (for example look at Spring and AOP-backed injection).

<sub>Note: the first version is not thread safe in the pasted snippet</sub>

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on the advantages of both methods?

Comment: It depends what MyClass is doing in its constructor. For instance, if you load data from a database to fill a cache and it takes 30 seconds and if you have other classes like this, the whole startup process could take some time. That could be optimized, especially if not all of these classes are needed directly after launching the application. If MyClass can be instantiated immediately, then your second solution is absolutely appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have first described is known as lazy instantiation, i.e the object will only be created when it is first called. This method is not thread-safe as it is possible for a second thread to create a second instance.

If you read the following book:

> Effective Java by Joshua Bloch

He explains that the best implementation of the singleton pattern is through the use of an `Enum` :

```
public enum Singleton {

  INSTANCE;

  public void doSomething() {
     ...
  }

}
```

Then you would call your singleton through the `Enum` as follows:

```
public class Test {

    public void test(){
        Singleton.INSTANCE.doSomething();
    }
}
```

This fits nicely with what you are saying in terms of it looks nicer and shorter to write but also guarantees there can never be a second instance.

Comment: This is indeed the best and recommended way. You get the lazy-loading "for free", but keep the mechanism incredibly simple.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two reasons:

The first is **Encapsulation**: you might have second thoughts about how and when your singleton is initialized, after your class has been exposed to client code. And an initialization method gives you more freedom as to changing your strategy later on. For example you might change your mind and decide to use two different constructors instead of one, according to another static variable's value at runtime. With your solution you're bound to using just one constructor at the time your class is loaded into memory, whereas with `getInstance()` you can change the initialization logic without affecting the interface to the client code.

The second is **Lazy Initialization** : with the conventional singleton implementation the `MyClass` object is loaded into memory only when needed by the client code for the first time.  And if the client code doesn't need it at all, you save on the memory allocated by your application. Note that whether your singleton is needed or not might not be certain until the program runs. For example it might depend on the user interaction with the program.

However the Lazy Initialization is not something you might necessarily want. For example if you're programming an interactive system and the initialization of your singleton is time consuming, it might actually be better to initialize it when the program is loading rather than when the user is already interacting with it, cause the latter might cause a latency in your system response the first time `getInstance()` is called. But in this case you can just have your instance initialized with the public method as in:

```
private static MyClass instance = getInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to synchronize the threads is using Double Checked (to ensure that only one thread will enter the synchronized block at a time and  to avoid obtaining the lock every time the code is executed).

```
public class DoubleCheckLocking {

    public static class SearchBox {
        private static volatile SearchBox searchBox;

        // private attribute of this class
        private String searchWord = "";
        private String[] list = new String[]{"Stack", "Overflow"};

        // private constructor
        private SearchBox() {}

        // static method to get instance
        public static SearchBox getInstance() {
            if (searchBox == null) { // first time lock
                synchronized (SearchBox.class) {
                    if (searchBox == null) {  // second time lock
                        searchBox = new SearchBox();
                    }
                }
            }
            return searchBox;
        }
}
```

Comment: Best way is to use an `enum` singleton. DCL is so 90's.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection: Reflection can be caused to destroy singleton 
property of singleton class, as shown in following example:

```
 // Java code to explain effect of Reflection 

 import java.lang.reflect.Constructor; 

 // Singleton class 
 class Singleton  
 { 
     // public instance initialized when loading the class 
     public static Singleton instance = new Singleton(); 

     private Singleton()  
     { 
         // private constructor 
     } 
 } 

 public class GFG  
 { 

     public static void main(String[] args) 
     { 
         Singleton instance1 = Singleton.instance; 
         Singleton instance2 = null; 
         try
         { 
             Constructor[] constructors =  
                     Singleton.class.getDeclaredConstructors(); 
             for (Constructor constructor : constructors)  
             { 
                 // Below code will destroy the singleton pattern 
                 constructor.setAccessible(true); 
                 instance2 = (Singleton) constructor.newInstance(); 
                 break; 
             } 
         } 

         catch (Exception e)  
         { 
             e.printStackTrace(); 
         } 

     System.out.println("instance1.hashCode():- " 
                                       + instance1.hashCode()); //366712642
     System.out.println("instance2.hashCode():- " 
                                       + instance2.hashCode()); //1829164700
     } 
 }
```